# Simple percentage problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am have trouble with this simple algebra question and I'm a little bit confused. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the question:

**How many liters of a 25% saline solution should be added to 3 of 10%
   saline solutions to get a 15% saline solution?**

Comment: Just write it out.  Your original sample has $.3$ L of salt, $2.7$ L of water.   $x$ L of the stronger solution will have $.25x$ L of salt and $.75x$ L of water.  Now look at the totals and make the ratio $.15$

Answer (score 1):

Let the number of litres of 25% saline you require be $x$.

$$0.25x + 0.1(3) = 0.15(x+3)$$

Solve for $x$!

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects: volume and salinity.

Volume is measured in liters. You're asked for the number of liters of $25\%$ saline solution needed to make some amount of $15\%$ saline solution by mixing it with $3$ liters of $10\%$ saline solution.

Salinity is percentage of saline per unit volume. You're looking for a particular amount of saline per unit volume ($15\%$). In the end, the equation you write is for a particular amount of saline, which means that the volume comes along for the ride:

$$\text{saline} = \text{salinity} \cdot \text{volume}$$

Now we can write the equation. You have $3$ liters of $10\%$ saline, and are adding $x$ liters of $25\%$ saline. The total volume, then, is $x+3$ liters. Now we just say that the saline before equals the saline after:

$$0.25\cdot x + 0.1 \cdot 3 = 0.15 \cdot (x+3)$$

Now, it's algebra to solve for $x$.